# Deep linking the right page inside the webview

Tags: android, webview, deep-linking

I made a android webview app for our website. Now i want to add deep links to the app, like when somebody clicks a link of our website, you can open it with the webview app instead of chrome web browser. I added these to my manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="www.example.com" />
```

Now it opens the webview app when I click a link which is related to us, but it doesnt open the right page, its just starting the app again. But I want to open the directly the right page inside the webview app.

EDIT:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //added
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
```

But it seems that the variables action and data are not used.
I load the webview like this (for three languages).

```
 //loads the main website
 //sets the matching language
 web2.clearCache(true);
    String loc = Locale.getDefault().toString();
    if (loc.startsWith("de")) {
        web2.loadUrl("https://www.example.de");
    } else if (loc.startsWith("nl")) {
        web2.loadUrl("https://www.example.nl");
    } else {
        web2.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the intent data that your activity receives when its opened via deep link. Example in Kotlin:

```
class WebViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)
    val uri = intent.data
    webView.loadUrl(uri.toString())
}
```

Comment: Like now you can see above in the edit, i added some things to my code (https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html#testing-filters) but it doesnt work.

Comment: I just tried it using  adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://www.example.com" and it worked. I got the intent chooser and started my app instead of chrome

Comment: where do i have to add it? can you show me your example?

Comment: but again I just repeat what i have written above. the intent chooser appears and I can choose my app, but it starts normally and not the right/related page.

Answer (score 0):

Now I did it like this. That is the solution.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();

String loc = Locale.getDefault().toString();

    if (data==null && loc.startsWith("de")) {
        web2.loadUrl("https://www.example.de");
    } else if (data==null && loc.startsWith("nl")) {
        web2.loadUrl("https://www.example.nl");
    } else if (data==null && !loc.startsWith("de") && !loc.startsWith("nl")){
        web2.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
    } else {
        web2.loadUrl(data.toString());
    }
```